# Is it possible to affect a Lucene rank based on a numeric value?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have content with various numeric values, and a higher value indicates (theoretically) more valuable content, which I want to rank higher.

For instance:

- Average rating  (0 - 5)
- Number of comments (0 - whatever)
- Number of inbound link references from other pages (0 - whatever)
- Some arbitrary number I apply to indicate how important I feel the content is (1 - whatever)

These can be indexed by Lucene as a numeric value, but how can I tell Lucene to use this value in its ranking algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set this value using "Field.SetBoost" while indexing.

Comment: Yes, or you can set a boost at the document level, which will apply to all the fields of the document

Answer (score 1):

Depending how exactly you want to proceed, you can set boost while indexing as suggested by @L.B, or if you want to make it dynamic, i.e. at search time rather than indexing time, you can use `ValueSourceQuery` and `CustomScoreQuery`.

You can see example in the question I asked some time ago:
[Lucene custom scoring for numeric fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924937/lucene-custom-scoring-for-numeric-fields) (the example was tested with Lucene 3.0).