# Lucene scoring and ordering

Tags: java, lucene

I want to use Lucene (4.10) to be able to match and order all records in a database. I have indexed the records which contain data of a number of different items I want to match on.

An example of the data would look as follows

```
age: 35
fav_colour: red
fav_car_manufacturer: bmw
```

I want to return ALL the documents ordered from the closest matching descending which I can do based on the score.

I currently do this to build a query

```
MatchAllDocsQuery allDocsClause = new MatchAllDocsQuery();

TermQuery ageTerm = new TermQuery(new Term("age", "35"));
TermQuery colorTerm = new TermQuery(new Term("fav_color", "red"));
TermQuery carTerm = new TermQuery(new Term("fav_car_manufacturer", "bmw"));

BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(allDocsClause, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
query.add(ageTerm, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
query.add(colorTerm, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
query.add(carTerm, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

This returns a scored set of documents which is fine, but I have my doubts that this is working correctly.

My questions around this are

- Is this completely nonsensical and meaningless for matching? In that, I mean I can understand that filtering or exact matching would work well, but how would Lucene determine whether 80, red, ford is more or less relevant that 35, blue, lexus?
- Is the age 50 any closer to 35 (in the example) than say, 30 or 34?
- Is it possible to boost attribute values for fixed sets of data (i.e colours) - For example, in the query, search for my favourite colour = red with BOOST +10, then second favourite colour with BOOST +5, etc?

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924937/lucene-custom-scoring-for-numeric-fields, which shows how to use a CustomScoreQuery to score by numeric distance.  If you want "red" to match "pink" better than it matches "blue", you might be able to do something similar, again, with a CustomScoreQuery.